# Where the does sender's name in an e-mail come from and how can I change what name I send?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail

At work, we use Google Apps to host our e-mail and Outlook to access it.  I have a user who recently changed their name.  I changed their e-mail address and their account name, but when they send e-mail their old name still appears, no matter whether they send it using Outlook or the gmail web client.  For example, e-mail from them in the Gmail web client reads `Oldname newemailaddress@example.com` instead of `Newname newemailaddress@example.com`.  I'm trying to make the user's new name show up when they send an e-mail.

Where is the sender's name stored?  Is it a part of the e-mail specification, stored in some header somewhere, or is it stored in the e-mail client?

If it's possible, how do you change the sender's name in Gmail?

Comment: [Rename a user](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182084) shows how to make the name change. Is this how you accomplished it?

Comment: @CharlieRB, yes, that's how I changed the name.

Comment: When viewing an e-mail, look for an option to "view the full Header".  That refers to the SMTP header used by each e-mail message.  There's probably a line like `From: "Oldname" <newemailaddress@example.com>`  Your user probably has to change their e-mail settings for you (and every other recipient) to see their new name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gmail it's under Settings, Accounts and Import, Send Mail as

Comment: I forgot about this question, haha.  Anyway, this worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sending from Outlook (SMTP) you'll need to make sure you change the account settings to reflect the name.

1. Go to File->Info->Account Settings.
2. Find the SMTP account in the list and click 'Change...'
3. Under 'User Information' change the persons name.